# two way anova homogeneity between groups

Tags: r

RStudio.
How can I check homogeneity on two-way ANOVA by every group separate?

SSB|A1, SSB|A2, SSB|A3

I tried this

```
out <- with(DTa,SNK.test(Value,Client:Method,df,MSerror, group=TRUE))
```

print(out$groups)

But results show homogeneity between all together

Comment: The Newman–Keuls or Student–Newman–Keuls (SNK) method is a stepwise multiple comparisons procedure used to identify sample means that are significantly different from each othe

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newman%E2%80%93Keuls_method

Comment: what are you exactly trying to test?